# Draw a 2x1 grid without using a table

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to draw the following grid without using a table or bootstrap...just simple css? Is using a table the only way?

[image]

Comment: ul li with nth-child selector will be a good choice.

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

Comment: display: table is another option. Or you can just make the first column display flex.

Answer (score 2):

There can be numerous ways, This is just one example:

```css
.col,.container {
    border:1px solid #000000;
  }
.row1 {
    display:flex;
  }
.col {
    flex:1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="col">col1</div>
      <div class="col">col2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">row2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be cautious with flexbox if you care about IE 9 and lower : http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```css
.step1{
  position:relative;
  width:98%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
.left{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid #600;
}
.right{
  width:48%;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid #ff8800;
}
.step2{
  width:98%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="step1">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="step2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox with minimal mark up, keeping in mind brower compatability issues with flexbox: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
.container {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.col {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    flex-grow:1;
  }
.row {
    flex-basis:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">    
      <div class="col">col1</div>
      <div class="col">col2</div>    
      <div class="row">row</div>
</div>
```